# GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE workaround using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I was using `glPointSize` to set the size of a photon I was firing in a game to about 3 pixels. This is handy because I can zoom in and out, drawing everything else in world co-ords, and the photon is still easy to see.

However on some platforms (my really old linux laptop)  `GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE` is limited to one pixel. I need another way of drawing the photon, otherwise I may have to draw it as a filled circle in world co-ordinates where it will change in size according to zoom level and may become hard to see when zoomed out.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is the one you mentioned. Instead of a "filled circle" you could also draw it as a textured quad or triangle to save yourself a few vertices.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'm all for saving a few vertices!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Saving and then restoring Matrices which are used in transforming.

```
glPushMatrix();
//apply viewing transformations (e.g. in photon's coordinate system)
//and draw your photon here
glPopMatrix();  //restores back where you were working.
```